# Multiple application of puts

Tags: ruby

I have the following definition:

```
class AllVowels
  @@vowels = %w{a e i o u}
  def each
    @@vowels.each {|v| yield v}
  end
end
```

This code:

```
AllVowels.new.each {|vowels| puts vowels}
```

outputs the vowels only once:

```
a
e
i
o
u
```

whereas this code:

```
puts AllVowels.new.each {|vowel| puts vowel}
```

outputs the vowels twice like so:

```
a
e
i
o
u
a
e
i
o
u
```

Why do I get two copies of the vowels?

Comment: You have two `puts` - one before `AllVowels.new` and one within the block.

Comment: OK I see thanks I call puts twice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts AllVowels.new.each {|vowel| puts vowel}
```

`AllVowels.new.each` calls `puts vowel` for each item, resulting in the first `a e i o u`. Then, by virtue of Ruby’s implicit returns, it returns the return value of

```
@@vowels.each {|v| yield v}
```

which is `@@vowels` itself, to allow for chaining. Calling `puts` on that array results in the second `a e i o u`.

This might help clear things up:

```
vowels = AllVowels.new.each do |vowel|
    puts "In each, got #{vowel}"
end

puts "Outside of each, got #{vowels}"
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/1OVJykOq)

Comment: Just as a side note: I think the key thing to understand here is that `puts` will actually print each item on a separate line when given an array.

Comment: I call `puts` twice. Thank You